# Upload profile picture from storage to firebase storage (android)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have some code that's goal is to get a user selected image and upload it to firebase storage for use as there profile picture. I tried to achieve it like this:

```
private fun uploadImage() {

        val getIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        getIntent.type = "image/*"

        val pickIntent =
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        pickIntent.type = "image/*"

        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image")
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(pickIntent))

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE)
        val mSelectedImageFileUri = chooserIntent.data

        Log.d("test1", "$mSelectedImageFileUri")

            if (mSelectedImageFileUri != null) {
                val userid = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
                val sRef: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(
                    "users/ $userid/profile.jpg"
                )
                sRef.putFile(mSelectedImageFileUri!!)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                        taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl
                            .addOnSuccessListener { url ->
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        //error
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Image failed to upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

            }else{
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Image invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() 
              }

        }
```

I believe the first segment of code works as it enters the file selection screen all ok. I think the issue is the upload segment trying to upload the value as soon as the function is ran, without waiting for user input. I think this because as soon as click the button that runs this function, The toast displaying "image invalid" is shown instantly, not when the image is selected.

So how can I get the upload segment to wait for the user to select a image before attempting to upload it?

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Well if you use ACTION_PICK and startActivityForResult() then where do you get the selected uri? This is pretty basic.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong in your code at a first glance, but since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help, it's a working solution. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).